# Pandas for python - code failing to sort by a specific column added to the data

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Working with python and pandas and I have cleaned some data and added a new column and added some data. Now the dataframe refuses to sort for some reason. I have tried two different methods to ensure the column "Review_Score" is in numeric form and both work. I then tried to sort by name and it would not work either. Can anyone explain what when wrong here?

```
from itertools import count
from platform import platform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("video_game.csv")

#clean the data converting str to numbers where needed + drop unwanted columns
df = df.drop(columns=["NA_players", "EU_players", "JP_players", "Other_players", "Global_players", "User_Count", "Rating", "Critic_Count"])


df['User_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['User_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
df['User_Score'] = df['User_Score'].astype(float)

df['Critic_Score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Critic_Score'] ,errors='coerce')
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
df['Critic_Score'] = df['Critic_Score'].astype(float)

#filter all the NES games released in 1988 on the list
df2 = df.loc[(df['Platform'] == 'NES') & (df['Year_of_Release'] == 1988)]

score = [94, 78, 80, 76, 72, 43, 94, 95, 65, 35, 68]

#add new column and populate with the review scores from the list score

df2['Review_Score'] = score
#df2.Review_Score = df2.Review_Score.astype(float)
df2.Review_Score = pd.to_numeric(df2.Review_Score, errors='coerce')
df2.sort_values('Review_Score', ascending=True)

print(df2)
```

Comment: I think you need `inplace=True` so that it would apply the changes to the original dataframe (`df2.sort_values('Review_Score', ascending=True, inplace=True)`). Or you can do reassignment as such `df2 = df2.sort_values('Review_Score', ascending=True)`.

Comment: This worked thannks. But why did you not write it as an answer ?

Comment: Will add it as an answer ya! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the `sort_values` method, you will need to add an extra parameter `inplace=True` in order to apply the changes to the original dataframe. You could do it as such:

```py
df2.sort_values('Review_Score', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Another way you could apply the changes is by reassigning the dataframe to the original variable as such:

```py
df2 = df2.sort_values('Review_Score', ascending=True)
```